# Could not marshal in REST with XML format

Tags: java, xml, rest

I have a GET endpoint, it can return JSON and XML formats:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/json", "application/xml" })
@ResponseBody
public Object getV6Subnet(@RequestBody V6SubnetRequest requestBody){
   RestResponse<V6SUBNETREC> response = null;
   V6SUBNETREC wsSubnet = null; 
   // do something to set value for wsSubnet
   response = RESTfulUtil.buildSuccessResponse(wsSubnet);
   return response;
}
```

My RESTfulUtil class:

```
public class RESTfulUtil {
   public synchronized static RestResponse buildSuccessResponse(Object content){
      RestResponse response = new RestResponse();
      response.setContent(content);
      return response;
   }    
}
```

RestReponse

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="RestResponse")
@XmlSeeAlso({
        ErrorResponse.class,
        V6SUBNETREC.class,
        V4ADDRREC.class,
        V4SUBNETREC.class,
        LOCATIONREC.class,
        CONTACTREC.class,
})

public class RestResponse<T> extends SimpleRestResponse {

    @XmlElement
    private  T content;

    public T getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(T content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

And my SimpleRestResponse class:

```
public class SimpleRestResponse {
   private int code;
   private int httpStatusCode;

   public int getCode() {
       return code;
   }

   public void setCode(int code) {
      this.code = code;
   }

   @JsonIgnore
   public int getHttpStatusCode() {
      return httpStatusCode;
   }

   public void setHttpStatusCode(int httpStatusCode) {
      this.httpStatusCode = httpStatusCode;
   }
}
```

When I request JSON format, I get:

```
{"code":21,"content":{"error":"Subnet not found."}}
```

But when I request XML format, there's an error:

```
Could not marshal [ws.restful.model.RestResponse@56b97914]: null; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.MarshalException

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not marshal [com.lucent.qip.nb.ws.restful.model.RestResponse@56b97914]: null; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class com.lucent.qip.nb.ws.restful.model.ErrorResponse nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.lucent.qip.nb.ws.restful.model.ErrorResponse nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
    org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.writeToResult(Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.java:184)
    org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.java:66)
    org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:208)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:161)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:185)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:891)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:151)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    com.lucent.qip.utils.filters.ResponseHeaderFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeaderFilter.java:60)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    com.lucent.qip.nb.ws.restful.security.AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter.java:55)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

I can't show my web.xml and applicationContext.xml
I only can provide rest-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

        <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
        <annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" />

        <interceptors>
            <interceptor>
                <mapping path="/openstack" />
                <beans:bean
                    class="com.lucent.qip.nb.ws.restful.controller.OpenStackController"></beans:bean>
            </interceptor>
        </interceptors>

        <!-- for processing requests with annotated controller methods and set Message 
            Convertors from the list of convertors -->
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
            <beans:property name="messageConverters">
                <beans:list>
                    <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter" />
                    <beans:ref bean="xmlConverter" />
                </beans:list>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>

        <!-- To convert JSON to Object and vice versa -->
        <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />

        <!-- To convert XML to Object and vice versa -->
        <beans:bean id="xmlConverter"
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
            <beans:constructor-arg ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
            <beans:property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/xml" />
        </beans:bean>

        <!-- JAXB Classes to be marshalled -->
        <beans:bean id="jaxbMarshaller"
            class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
            <beans:property name="packagesToScan">
                <beans:list>
                    <beans:value>com.lucent.qip.nb.ws.restful.model</beans:value>
                </beans:list>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>

        <beans:bean id="JacksonObjectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper" />

        <beans:bean id="contentNegotiationManager"
            class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
            <beans:property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
            <beans:property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
            <beans:property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
            <beans:property name="useJaf" value="false" />

            <beans:property name="mediaTypes">
                <beans:map>
                    <beans:entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                    <beans:entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
                </beans:map>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.lucent.qip.nb.ws.restful.controller" />

    </beans:beans>
```

I also added @XmlRootElement for all of the class V6SUBNETREC, V4ADDRREC, ErrorResponse,
V4SUBNETREC, LOCATIONREC, CONTACTREC but also not solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem.
Actually, my project using jaxb 2.0, I tried to upgrade to 2.2 and it works without the need to edit anything more.
Thank @Tom Sebastian about your help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the current thread's JAXBContext doesn't know about the `content` of `RestResponse` or some other calsses the content depends on like `ErrorResponse`(from your stacktrace) . To resolve this you can introduce the needed classes to JAXBContext as follows.

First Annotate all classes that are need to be converted to xml should be annotated with `@XmlRootElement`

Then add following bean configuration for Spring's HttpMessageConvertors. Assuming you are using annotaion driven:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
            converters.add(marshallingMessageConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public MarshallingHttpMessageConverter marshallingMessageConverter() {
        MarshallingHttpMessageConverter converter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setMarshaller(jaxbMarshaller());
        converter.setUnmarshaller(jaxbMarshaller());
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean 
    public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxbMarshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.lucent.qip.nb.ws.restful.model");//you need to specify the package where your @XmlRootElement s reside
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        props.put(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(props);
        return marshaller;
    }
}
```

You can see inine comment in the above code, I specified the package of classes that need to be included in the JAXBcontext. 
Needed maven dependency is:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have tested with 4.1.5.RELEASE

Comment: Where should I put WebConfig class?

Comment: If you are using component scan then put it in the base package, so that spring configuration can load it.If you are using xml spring configurationsg please provide `web.xml` and root application context xml. I will guide you

Comment: can you see in your app context any thing like <context:component-scan base-package="some.package">

Comment: Oh man you have already the converters for xml and json, then it will be some other issue. What I gave is a corresponding java configuration only. I think your spring configurationis correct.

Comment: Can you check all your classes in the model package has `@XmlRootElement` annotation, especially `ErrorResponse` ?

Comment: I've added @XmlRootElement to the ErrorResponse still encounter errors.
Packge model so much class, I can not add annotation to all class

Comment: Did the error changed to some other class other than `ErrorResponse` class (previously in the stacktrace `com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class com.lucent.qip.nb.ws.restful.model.ErrorResponse nor any of its super class is known to this context.`)? Then try annotate them too.

Comment: Does not work for me using 4.1.6.RELEASE and spring-hateoas 0.19.0.RELEASE